# tr command not working with octal sequences

Tags: solaris, special-characters, tr

I need to strip non-ASCII characters off a file. I was using the command -

`/usr/xpg4/bin/tr -cd '\0-\177' <non-ASCII_file.dat >ASCII_file.dat`

Though it worked in the past, it is not working now. It is now stripping off all the alphabet along with non-ASCII characters. The only characters being left in the ASCII file are numbers and special characters in the ASCII set.

OS is Solaris 9.

What could be causing this issue? Is the Octal range being interpreted incorrectly? Something to do with my environment?

Comment: How about `strings <non-ASCII_file.dat >ASCII_file.txt`

Comment: Does it make a difference if you do `LC_ALL=C /usr/xpg4/bin/tr -cd '\0-\177'`?

Comment: If you have Ruby available http://stackoverflow.com/q/1268289/789593 might help.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas That did the trick. What is LC_ALL and what does setting it to 'C' signify and how does it affect `tr`? And could you please elaborate this in the answer section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behaviour of character ranges depend on the locale, that is the internationalisation settings. Different locales have different order for characters. For instance in a French locale (and most locales where there is a `â` character), `â` will be after `a` and before `b`.

The C locale is one that is not language specific (or US English specific when it has to make a choice), in that locale, characters are bytes and they sort by their byte value.

The locales area that `tr` is concerned about are `LC_CTYPE` to define the type of character, and `LC_COLLATE` to define the order of characters. Note that nowadays the characters have variable number of bytes as utf-8 is becoming more and more common as the default character set.

Those can be specified using environment variables of the same name. `LC_ALL` however overrides them all. So to be sure to get the behavior you want, you have to either unset LC_ALL and set the ones you like or simpler, just set LC_ALL:

```
LC_ALL=C tr -cd '\0-\177'
```

Or:

```
LC_ALL=C tr -d '\200-\377'
```

That also works for utf-8 data because utf-8 is a superset of ASCII and all the non-ASCII characters have the eighth bit set in all their bytes.

Comment: Good point about UTF-8.  Which raises the question, "Why does anyone do anything other than UTF-8?"

Comment: @BruceEdiger Legacy, and binary files.

Comment: @BruceEdiger: [History for one](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), not to mention other uses as e.g. SMS where one can cram a lot more then 140 characters in 140 8 bit bytes (octets). It depends on use. If you have an application that are only going to process ASCII - adding support for UTF would mean raising the complexity of the code by N levels. Especially with lower languages as C. It's void to e.g. say your application support UTF-8, but only for the 127 first code points.

Comment: I should have written a clearer question: "Why does anyone do any other encoding of Unicode other than UTF-8?" Living as I do in the middle of North America, I write personal use programs for ASCII only, so I understand the history and "other uses" aspects.